# How can I make a timer animation in the command line?

Tags: php, animation, command-line, timer

This is a little silly, but something I've wanted to do before and could never figure out. I have a PHP script that runs from the command line. I'd like a little timer animation to let the user know the script is still running. Here's what I have:

```
while (1 == 1) {
   echo '—';
   usleep(100000);
   echo '\';
   usleep(100000);
   echo '|';
   usleep(100000);
   echo '/';
}
```

But how do I get each echo to *replace* the character before it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to print a backspace before each character, for example:-

```
echo '-';
usleep(100000);
echo "\b/";
```

Note that you have to use double quotes here or the escape sequence won't work.

I'm sure you can work the rest out :)

If "\b" doesn't work try:-

```
echo chr(8) . '/';
```

Comment: This seemed like the simplest solution - I tried `\b` before asking the question but it didn't work. `cur(8)` did the trick!

Answer (score 1):

Try the php ncurses extension:

http://php.net/manual/en/ref.ncurses.php

Comment: Wow - this is a cool extension. I'm going to look into this for sure - maybe a bit overkill for this though.

Answer (score 1):

You can use

```
echo "yourCharacter1\r";
usleep(100000);
echo "yourCharacter1\r";
```

or

```
echo "\ryourCharacter1\r";
usleep(100000);
echo "\ryourCharacter2\r";
```

`\r` sends the cursor back to position 0 on the same line.

Also you may try (found online)

```
system("clear"); // before you echo new characters
```

or

```
passthru('clear'); // before you echo new characters
```